# WebGL creating multiple objects?

Tags: graphics, webgl, graphics2d

So I am trying to create circles using the midpoint algorithm. I'm having trouble on how to handle buffers and basically get WebGL properly set up. Using the console I can see that the algorithm is working fine and making the vertex arrray, but I need help understanding what to do with the use.Program, createBuffers, drawArrays. Where should I place them?

Also, should I concat the circle everytime I call it in the START() function?

like: circle(blah blah).concat(circle(blah blah));

```js
var vertexShaderText = 
[
'precision mediump float;',
'',
'attribute vec2 vertPosition;',
'attribute vec3 vertColor;',
'varying vec3 fragColor;',
'',
'void main()',
'{',
'  fragColor = vertColor;',
'  gl_Position = vec4(vertPosition, 0.0, 1.0);',
'}'
].join('\n');

var fragmentShaderText =
[
'precision mediump float;',
'',
'varying vec3 fragColor;',
'void main()',
'{',
'  gl_FragColor = vec4(fragColor, 1.0);',
'}'
].join('\n');


var START = function () {
  console.log('This is working');

  var canvas = document.getElementById('sky');
  var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

  if (!gl) {
    console.log('WebGL not supported, falling back on  experimental-webgl');
    gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
  }

  if (!gl) {
    alert('Your browser does not support WebGL');
  }

  gl.clearColor(.3, .3, .7, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


  // Create shaders

  var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  var fragmentShader = 
     gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderText);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderText);

  //create a program for the shaders
  var program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  gl.useProgram(program);

    var circle = function (xmid, ymid, r) {
  var points = [];
  var x = 0;
  var y = r;
  var pk = 5/4 - r;
  while (x < y)
  {
    if (pk < 0)
    {
      x++;
      pk += 2*x + 1;
    }
    else
    {
      x++;
      y--;
      pk += 2 * (x-y) + 1;
    }
    points.push(x+xmid, y+ymid);
    points.push(x+xmid, -y+ymid);
    points.push(-x+xmid, y+ymid);
    points.push(-x+xmid, -y+ymid);
    points.push(y+xmid, x+ymid);
    points.push(y+xmid, -x+ymid);
    points.push(-y+xmid, x+ymid);
    points.push(-y+xmid, -x+ymid);
  }

  var cbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cbuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(points), 
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, points.length/2);

  var positionAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 
   'vertPosition');
  var colorAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 
   'vertColor');

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionAttribLocation, // Attribute location
    2, // Number of elements per attribute
    gl.FLOAT, // Type of elements
    gl.FALSE,
    5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, // Size of an  individual vertex
    0 // Offset from the beginning of a single vertex to this attribute
  );

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocation);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribLocation);

  return points;

  }

  circle(0.6, 0.6, 0.18);

  circle(0.9, 0.6, 0.18);

  circle(0.5, 0.4, 0.18);

  circle(1.0, 0.4, 0.18);

  circle(0.75, 0.4, 0.18);

  circle(0.75, 0.4, 0.18);


}

START();
```

```html
<canvas id="sky"></canvas>
```

This is what my console log is saying:

```
 6WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not 
 valid
 6WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: no valid shader 
 program in use
 12WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getAttribLocation: program 
 not linked
```

You can clearly see that I am linking and using the program at the very beginning. So what gives?

Comment: How about starting with some basic [WebGL fundamentals](https://webglfundamentals.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one issue with the code

1. The shaders are not compiled

   After setting the shader source with `gl.shaderSource` you need
   to compile them with `gl.compileShader`. You should also
   be checking for errors by calling `gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)`
   and you should be checking for errors after linking by calling
   `gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)`
2. `gl.drawArrays` is called before setting the attributes
3. The code is enabling 2 attributes but only supplying data for 1 attribute.
4. The code is drawing `gl.POINTS` but the vertex shader is not setting `gl_PointSize`

I also don't really understand your circle code but since I don't know what it's really trying to do I can't *fix* it.

And finally you should probably read [some tutorials on WebGL](http://webglfundamentals.org)

I'd also suggest you use multiline template literals for your shaders

```js
const vertexShaderText = `
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 vertPosition;
attribute vec3 vertColor;
varying vec3 fragColor;

void main()
{
  fragColor = vertColor;
  gl_Position = vec4(vertPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl_PointSize = 5.;
}
`;

const fragmentShaderText = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 fragColor;
void main()
{
  gl_FragColor = vec4(fragColor, 1.0);
}
`;

const start = function () {
  console.log('This is working');

  const canvas = document.getElementById('sky');
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

  if (!gl) {
    alert('Your browser does not support WebGL');
    return;
  }

  gl.clearColor(.3, .3, .7, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  //create a shader program 
  const program = createProgram(gl, vertexShaderText, fragmentShaderText);
  gl.useProgram(program);

  const circle = function (xmid, ymid, r) {
    const points = [];
    let x = 0;
    let y = r;
    let pk = 5/4 - r;
    while (x < y)
    {
      if (pk < 0)
      {
        x++;
        pk += 2*x + 1;
      }
      else
      {
        x++;
        y--;
        pk += 2 * (x-y) + 1;
      }
      points.push(x+xmid, y+ymid);
      points.push(x+xmid, -y+ymid);
      points.push(-x+xmid, y+ymid);
      points.push(-x+xmid, -y+ymid);
      points.push(y+xmid, x+ymid);
      points.push(y+xmid, -x+ymid);
      points.push(-y+xmid, x+ymid);
      points.push(-y+xmid, -x+ymid);
    }

    const cbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cbuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    const positionAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'vertPosition');
    const colorAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'vertColor');

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      positionAttribLocation, // Attribute location
      2, // Number of elements per attribute
      gl.FLOAT, // Type of elements
      gl.FALSE,
      0, // Size of an  individual vertex
      0 // Offset from the beginning of a single vertex to this attribute
    );

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocation);
    
    // you probably meant to supply colors for this attribute
    // since if you wanted a constant color you'd have probably
    // used a uniform but since you didn't we'll set a constant
    // color
    gl.vertexAttrib4f(colorAttribLocation, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, points.length/2);

    return points;

  }

  circle(0.6, 0.6, 0.18);
  circle(0.9, 0.6, 0.18);
  circle(0.5, 0.4, 0.18);
  circle(1.0, 0.4, 0.18);
  circle(0.75, 0.4, 0.18);
  circle(0.75, 0.4, 0.18);
}

function createProgram(gl, vertexShaderText, fragmentShaderText) {
  // Create shaders
  const vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderText);
  const fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderText);

  const program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    gl.deleteProgram(program);
    return null;
  }
  return program;  
}

function createShader(gl, type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
    return null;
  }
  return shader;
}

start();
```

```html
<canvas id="sky"></canvas>
```